# regexp excluye char

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regexp that has the following characteristics.

1. Begin by **{{**
2. may contain line breaks and any character
3. may not contain **}}**

**example**

**This is ok.

{{ dog car blue #hello#

**This is not ok.**

{{ dog car blue }} #hello#

I tried it with the regexp:

```
{{2}([\s\S]*?)[^\{]#hello#
```

but always returns ok

Comment: That is a bit not clear: do you want to match from `{{` up to `#hello#`? Or up to `}}`? Or up to the end of line/string?

Comment: I think it is only that the string 1) should always start with `{{` (this should never appear in midsentence) and 2) should have `#hello#` word.

Comment: I could suggest `{{(?:(?!#hello#|{{)[\s\S])*#hello#`, but it is prone to catastrophical backtracking. Try [`{{[^#{]*(?:{(?!{)[^#{]*|#(?!hellow#)[^#{]*)*#hello#`](https://regex101.com/r/zT3qY3/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now that the question is updated, it has become more unclear.

Comment: Hello I edit my question to try to find an easier vision of my problem. Thanks

Comment: Try [`^{{[^#}]*(?:}(?!})[^#}]*|#(?!hellow#)[^#}]*)*#hello#`](https://regex101.com/r/zT3qY3/2) then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a tempered greedy token solution because you need to first match a multicharacter leading delimiter `{{` and then you need to match *any text other than `#hello#` and `{{` (multicharacter sequences)*. If you had to negate only one character, `[^{]` would suffice. It is not the case here.

Use

```
/{{[^#}]*(?:}(?!})[^#}]*|#(?!hellow#)[^#}]*)*#hello#/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cX2qE2/1)

Note that it is an unrolled variant of [`{{(?:(?!}}|#hellow#)[\s\S])*#hello#`](https://regex101.com/r/nI5kI1/1) which is more readable but is highly inefficient and much more prone to catastrophic backtracking issue.

Details:

- `{{` - matches `{{`
- `[^#}]*`  - 0+ characters other than `#` and `}`
- `(?:}(?!})[^#}]*|#(?!hellow#)[^#}]*)*` - matches 0+ sequences of either

  - `}(?!})[^#}]*` - `}` not followed with `}` and then followed with 1+ characters other than `#` and `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `#(?!hellow#)[^#}]*` - a `#` that is not followed with `hello#` and then followed with 1+ characters other than `#` and `}`
- `#hello#` - `#hello#`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation. It is perfect

Answer (score 1):

This one handles newline characters as well. So your selection can be over along multiple lines.

```
{{[^{]*#hello#
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OZmMHipJJuQVyaiS)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR0aW7/1)

```js
var str = "{{House () dog {{ dog #hello#";
str = str.match(/{{[^{]*#hello#/g)[0];
document.write(str);
```

Comment: hello, as could exclude {{ and not only {. I need to exclude when the character twice.
Thanks

Comment: @rv4 try this `[^{]*#hello#`

Comment: @rv4: Please have a look at my comment above. The `{{[^{]*#hello#`  will not match anything if there is `{` in between `{{` and `#hello#`. You need  either a tempered greedy token, or an unrolled (as in my comment) tempered greedy token. As I see, you do not need anchoring at the start of the string, just remove `^`. Try `{{[^#}]*(?:}(?!})[^#}]*|#(?!hellow#)[^#}]*)*#hello#`